# Is there a function whose derivative is positive and the derivative of its inverse is negative?

Tags: functions, derivatives, inverse-function

Does there exist some bijective function $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)$ is positive everywhere and $(f^{-1})'(x)$ is negative everywhere?

Comment: Do you mean everywhere, or just at one point, or...?

Comment: I mean everywhere.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

As to your question, what do you think?

Comment: You know the formula $(f^{-1})'(y) = 1/f'(x)$ (provided $f'(x) \neq 0$)...? :)

Comment: Then no.  Sketch a graph of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ for a few examples and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Desmos.com is a great graphing calculator.  Plug in $y = x+3$ for $f$ and $y = x-3$ for $f^{-1}$.  Then do $x^2$ and $\sqrt(x)$.  Then $e^x$ and $\ln x$.  $1/x$ is its own inverse.  Do you see the symmetry across the diagonal?

Comment: Thank you @RobertTheTutor. I usually use Geogebra. But I liked Desmos too.

Answer (score 0):

A function and its inverse function are symmetric in respect to the line $y=x$. So, if the initial function is growing, so would its inverse, just at slower pace.

From any point on the plot of initial function you can draw a normal to the $y=x$ line and find the corresponding point of the inverse function. At that point it will have derivative inverse to the derivative of initial function where it is intersecting the normal.

Since $1/x$ has the same sign as $x$, the bothe will have the same sign.

Comment: Since the inverse of the inverse is the original function you can't say that "the inverse function is growing at a slower pace". Reversing the roles would show growth at a faster pace. Think about $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = x/2$.

Answer (score 0):

For the function: $y = e^x ~ | ~0 < x < 1 $, I believe I have achieved the desired effect.